# JAX-RS for consuming JSON file generates Error 415

Tags: json, rest, gradle, jersey, jax-rs

I would like create a REST service, with JAX-RS and Jersey, for consuming JSON structure.

I'm using org.glassfish.jersey and gradle, so I inserted into gradle-build file :

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet-core', version: '2.26-b03'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-multipart', version: '2.26-b03'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-common', version: '2.26-b03'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-server', version: '2.26-b03'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.26-b03'
```

I activated the POJO mapping feature in web.xml:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I wrote a simple class for managing JSON entity and I use the XMLElement annotation.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="polygongjson")
public class PolygonGJson {

    @XmlElement(name="type")
    String type;
    @XmlElement(name="properties")
    String properties;
    @XmlElement(name="geometry")
    String geometry;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(String properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public String getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }

    public void setGeometry(String geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Track [type=" + type + ", properties=" + properties + ", geometry=" + geometry +"]";
    }
}
```

Finally I created the REST method for consuming JSON structure through POST.

```
Path("/upload")
public class UploadRaster extends Application {

    @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Path("/j_geojson/{id_user}")
        public Response uploadGeoJSON(@PathParam("id_user") String id_user,
                                      PolygonGJson polyIn){


            try{

                System.out.println("JSON: "+polyIn.toString());
                return Response.status(200).entity(polyIn.getGeometry()).build();

            }catch(Exception e){

                return Response.status(500).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
            }
        }
}
```

I prepared a simple json file :

```
{
   "type": "Feature",
   "properties": "test prop",
   "geometry": "test geo"
}
```

In order to test my method, I used curl in this way:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @./testgjsimple.json https://myserver:8443/mywarfile/api/upload/j_geojson/1
```

but server respond with:

```
HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type
Unsupported Media Type
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

NOTE: my Application server is Tomcat 7.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know XML and JSON structures are handled diffrently. So the part:

```
...
@XmlRootElement(name="polygongjson")
public class PolygonGJson {
    @XmlElement(name="type")
    String type;
...
```

can cause, that JSON can not be used properly.

Try it without annotations like that (it must be working):

```
...
public class PolygonGJson {
    String type;
...
```

or if you would like to adjust some special things, use annotations for JSON (I would prefer jackson).

Comment: thanks for you suggestions, I used Xml annotation following Jersey documentation and examples for management JSON structures as well as Xml structures, I'm looking for specific JSON annotations but I'm not able to find anything... anyway I'm going to try your suggestion

Comment: I never use Jackson, I don't known the difference between jackson and jersey

Comment: unfortunately your solution didn't work. I will try using Jackson library

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well with Jersey 2.33. After carefully reading the doc:https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-b

I found out we need to register the json provider unless we use the default provider: jersey-media-json-binding.

So for your case, you can add another dependency:

`compile "org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-binding:2.26"`

Comment: Thnaks for your suggestion, I'll try it asap